# How Express js module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am beginner at Node js. Can someone explain me where this function **express()** come from.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
```

In my reasoning const express stores the 'express' object, so why here is function called? Instead of method or property.

```
const app = express()
```

Comment: you use NPM (package manager) to include the plugin "express" - if you include it with NPM a "node_modules" folder will contain the 'express' code. Node knows when you use 'require(..." to first check to see if the package is in the node_modules folder.   The "express" code returns a function that can be executed : express()

Comment: `cosnt express` stores the `createAplication`: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/e1b45ebd050b6f06aa38cda5aaf0c21708b0c71e/lib/express.js#L28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions are just a type of object.

Therefore, anything you can do to an object, you can do to a function.

```js
function foo() {
    console.log("I am foo");
}

foo.property = "value";

console.log(1, typeof foo);
console.log(2, foo instanceof Function);
console.log(3, foo instanceof Object);
console.log(4, foo.property);

foo();
```

In this case, the object exported by the *express* module is a function.